# query_posts not working after wordpress 3.7 update

Tags: wordpress

I recently updated to wordpress 3.7 and all of a sudden my posts page stopped working . it shows nothing and opens up a blank page . there is small code on that page and it stopped working . It was using `query_posts` to get the posts but now a bank page shows up .

the code

```
    <? query_posts ('cat=-103&posts_per_page=1') ?>

 <? while (have_posts ()) { the_post ();  ?>

    <div class="reu-sec">

        <h2><a href="<? the_permalink() ?>"><? the_title (); ?><span class="sbttlmn"> &nbsp <?= get_post_meta (get_the_ID(), 'sub-title', true); ?></span></a></h2>

        <div class="desc">

            <? //the_content ('[More]'); ?>

            <div class="reu-prev1"><a href="<? the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?= get_post_meta (get_the_ID(), 'image', true); ?>"/></a></div>

            <div class="reu-prev2"><a href="<? the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?= get_post_meta (get_the_ID(), 'image2', true); ?>"/></a></div>

            <div class="reu-prev3"><a href="<? the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?= get_post_meta (get_the_ID(), 'image3', true); ?>"/></a></div>

        </div>

        <div style="clear: both"></div>

    </div>

<?php }  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As for a beginning, enable `WP_DEBUG` in `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

Then go back to the page in question and you should see a PHP Fatal error(I assume) or some other error message describing where that issue is coming from - once you get that, post it here(you should remove the full path information for privacy concerns).

If you can't possibly do that, try switching the short-hand php tags to normal tags. That means replace all occurrences of `<?=` with `<?php echo` and all `<?` with `<?php`. Generally those shouldn't cause the issue, but I just can't find anything else that could possibly cause an issue.

Comment: the main problem is that its working for the users who are logined but not working for the users who are not logined

Comment: Hm... Still - did you try to get WP_DEBUG and see if something shows up? If you don't want to enable WP_DEBUG for all of your visitors, you can simply do something like that: `if ( isset( $_GET['testing'] ) ) { define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); } else { define( 'WP_DEBUG', false ); }` Then just go to your page in question and add ?testing to the end of the URL.